# Undefined behavior when passing C++ objects to C routine

Tags: c++, c, numeric

**Update**

I found that if I pass by reference in the constructor, then it fix the problem in A.cpp!

i.e. `InfoPass(vector<double> &arg0, vector<double> &arg1...)`, but what's the reason?

**Update**

Basically I want to call some c code from c++.

as explained in the c mannual, to avoid using gloabal variables, a "void *fdata" is provided to get addtional information, if not any, it's pointed to NULL.

```
int f(unsigned ndim, unsigned npts, const double *x, void *fdata,
      unsigned fdim, double *fval);
```

Now I need to pack some c++ objects and pass to "f" through this *fdata argument, the way I could think of is to define a class "InfoPass", and pass it to the c routine.

my c++ snippet (example A.cpp and B.cpp,   A doesn't work properly while B is OK):

```
// Example A.cpp
#include "cubature.h"   // the c library called cubature
#include "extern_cpp_class.hpp" //

class InfoPass
{
    public:
        extern_cpp_class obj1;
        extern_cpp_class obj2;
        extern_cpp_class obj3;
        double arr[3];  

        InfoPass(vector<double>arg0, vector<double>arg1, vector<double>arg2, vector<double>arg3)      
            : obj1{arg0, arg1}, obj2{arg0, arg2}, obj3{arg0, arg3} {}
};

// the declaration of int f() and cubature() below are in the c code
int f(unsigned ndim, const double *x,  void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval);

int main() {
    /*** do something  ***/
    InfoPass cubpass{arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3};  // initialize
    cubature(2, f, &cubpass, 2, xmin, xmax, 1e5, 0, 1e-5, ERROR_PAIRED, OUTPUT, &err);
    /*** process with output ***/
}

int f(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval)
{
    InfoPass *fcubpass=static_cast<InfoPass*>(fdata);
    /*** do things with fcubpass.obj1, .obj2 ...  ***/
}
```

Now, I can compile(gcc) and run example A, strangely, there are undefinded behaviors, sometimes it gives NaN, sometimes gives very crazy numbers...

However, if instead I do in the following way (Example B, use pointers to class) then use "new" in f, it works fine!  wondering why? since I prefer the Example A to B in which I need to alway "new" somthing...

```
// Example B.cpp
class InfoPass
{
    public:
        extern_cpp_class *obj1=NULL;
        extern_cpp_class *obj2=NULL;
        extern_cpp_class *obj3=NULL;
        double arr[3];

        ~InfoPass(){
            delete obj1;
            delete obj2;
            delete obj3;
        }
}

int main() {
    /*** do something  ***/

    InfoPass cubpass;  // declare
    cubpass.obj1 = new extern_cpp_class(arg0,arg1);
    cubpass.obj2 = new extern_cpp_class(arg0,arg2);
    cubpass.obj3 = new extern_cpp_class(arg0,arg3);
    cubature(2, f, &cubpass, 2, xmin, xmax, 1e5, 0, 1e-5, ERROR_PAIRED, OUTPUT, &err);

    /*** process with output ***/
}

int f(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval)
{
    InfoPass *fcubpass=static_cast<InfoPass*>(fdata);

    /*** do things with fcubpass->obj1, .obj2 ...  ***/ 
}
```

Comment: C++ allows to use `static_cast<>` to cast any pointer to `void*` and if you cast that `void*` back to the original pointer type using `static_cast<>` you get the same pointer, so this is not UB.

Comment: f is a callback you define, don't you? The C code doesn't touch the `void*`, it's opaque to it.

Comment: @dom0 no, the prototype of f is defined in the C code, also the void*, anyway, "B.cpp" use the same pointer cast, and it works fine.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean, that the f you pass to cubature is an f you defined yourself in your C++ code.

Comment: @dom0, yes, and the second example "B.cpp" works fine, can you give some explanation?

Comment: Seems it expects that obj members are pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here.

What do `extern_cpp_class` objects do with their initialization parameters?  If they take and store their `vector` arguments as references, you'd run into trouble with the original `A.cpp` since the arguments are temporary copies that are destroyed — invalidating the references — after `cubpass`'s constructor is finished executing.  Switching to passing references would fix this by ensuring that the `extern_cpp_class` objects receive references to `vector`s created in `main` that (presumably) remain valid until the program exits (or at least until you're done working with `cubpass`).  In `B.cpp`, the constructors already get references to such `vector`s, hence no problems.

Comment: "since the arguments are temporary copies that are destroyed — invalidating the references", could you give some reference on this point?

Comment: When you pass a variable into a function, it's copied unless the function specifically asks for a reference.  In the original `A.cpp` the `InfoPass` constructor takes its arguments "normally," so copies are made.  The `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3` inside the constructor are (deep) _copies_ of the `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3` in `main` — they're entirely new variables.

Comment: Inside the `InfoPass` constructor, they're just like ordinary variables, and you can safely pass them into the `extern_cpp_class` constructors.  However, _if_ those constructors try to store them as references, there will be trouble.  The problem is that the `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3` _inside_ the `InfoPass` constructor will be destroyed when they go out of scope, i.e., when that constructor is finished executing.  That will leave the references stored in the `extern_cpp_class` objects pointing at garbage.

Comment: But as I noted, this is just a guess.  It's possible that the `extern_cpp_class` constructor doesn't do anything like this and that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: but normally pass by value is ok in the constructor, isn't it ?

Comment: What matters is what the constructor _does_ with what you pass it.  If it stores a reference, you have to ensure that you don't destroy the original before the constructed object is done with it.

Comment: If it makes and stores its own copy, then either way should be fine.

Comment: You should be able to look at `extern_cpp_class.hpp` to see how `extern_cpp_class`es use their initialization parameters.  Alternatively, there might be some associated documentation that will reveal what's going on.

Comment: you are right, extern_cpp_class use the vector arguments as references.

Comment: BTW, could you explain why " In B.cpp, the constructors already get references to such vectors, hence no problems."?

Comment: In `B.cpp` there are statements like `cubpass.obj1 = new extern_cpp_class(arg0,arg1)`.  In this statement, `new` constructs and returns a pointer to an `extern_cpp_class` object, using `arg0` and `arg1` as the arguments to the constructor.  Since `arg0` and `arg1` were created in `main` and won't be destroyed until they go out of scope, the references should last until the program exits.  This is different from `A.cpp` in which the `vector`s are first _copied_ into the `InfoPass` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Since `f` should be the Callback function that is called by C-code it should use c's calling convention.

But since you declare and define it in cpp it uses another calling convention.
So maybe the parameter passing somehow goes wrong.

Try adding `extern "C"` in front of the declaration of `f`.

But this obviously does not satisfactorily explain, why one of your examples does work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the initialization list in your InfoClass constructor to use parenthesis instead of curly braces?

```
obj1(arg0, arg1), obj2(arg0, arg2), obj3(arg0, arg3)
```

P.S. I would have posted this as a comment, but I dont have the reputations yet.

Comment: Is the function f called from inside the cubature function? Is it called in a different thread? If yes, then there could be a problem in accessing variables defined on the stack.

Comment: yes, it's called from inside cubature. no, the current code is sequential.

Comment: Is it just the vector member which have a problem or all members?

Comment: What I meant to ask was what exactly got messed up? the vectors inside cubpass or all the members inside cubpass?

Comment: If you're running under Linux try to check with valgrind what's up there with memory access. Things like these with weirdo behaviour are often memory access issues.